# Why is flaskform refusing to display the errors from the fields when submitted but not validated?

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms

I'm just learning flask. I wanted to display the errors I get in the fields from flask form on my web page but it just wont show. Example when I submit without filling in any data, it doesn't give me the the error "This field is required" to style it the way I want. The errors just wont show. Please help a brother.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, flash, redirect, url_for
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Length, EqualTo

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'your_secret_key'

class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=4, max=20)])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=6)])
    confirm_password = PasswordField('Confirm Password', validators=[DataRequired(),  
                         EqualTo('password')])     
    submit = SubmitField('Register')

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    form = RegistrationForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        flash(f'Account created for {form.username.data}!', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('register'))
    return render_template('register.html', form=form)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Registration Form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Register</h1>
    <form method="POST" action="">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        <div>
            {{ form.username.label }}<br>
            {{ form.username(size=32) }}<br>
            {% for error in form.username.errors %}
                <span style="color: red;">{{ error }}</span><br>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <div>
            {{ form.password.label }}<br>
            {{ form.password(size=32) }}<br>
            {% for error in form.password.errors %}
                <span style="color: red;">{{ error }}</span><br>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <div>
            {{ form.confirm_password.label }}<br>
            {{ form.confirm_password(size=32) }}<br>
            {% for error in form.confirm_password.errors %}
                <span style="color: red;">{{ error }}</span><br>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <div>
            {{ form.submit() }}
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```